# Rendering a partial in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I'm wondering how I could render a partial in a javascript asset.

What I'm aiming at:

```
# in /app/assets/javascript/cart.js.coffee.erb
$('a.add_sth').click -> $('.random_container').append('<%= render partial: 'way/to/partial' %>')
```

This causes a NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fc54584c6e8>:0x007fc5474cd470>
```

If I write `<%= 2+3 %>` instead it works fine, btw.

I think the problem is that the asset pipeline is independent from the default ActionView and that's why `render()` is unknown there. Anyway, is there a way to get that partial's content rendered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bad news, render is not available
Look: [same question on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1370)

Answer (score 5):

Remember that assets are meant for static data, like CSS, JS or images that will not dynamically change its contents, so they can be better cached and/or exported to a CDN.

Since you are allowed to run ERB with ruby code, it should always return the same value (since it will be executed only when compiling the asset).

That's why I guess *render* is not available inside assets (although it could be properly used to render static data).

Easy solution here: **move your JS file to a view**, there you will be able to use any view helper.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. (for HAML)

```
= Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/xxxxx','_form.html.haml'))).render(Object.new, :hello => "Hello World")
```

And, needed to add dependency in the beginning of file to be updated like:
In this case, the depended file is needed to be in the asset.

```
//= depend_on xxxxx/_form.html.haml
```

Comment: For some reasons `render` puts a new line at the end and makes js code invalid. Fixed by adding `chomp` after `render`

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.2

I found this post https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/90
which suggests using <% require_asset 'path/to/file' %>

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, so I wrote this `render` method, that can be used inside assets to render **ERB** partial template:

```
# in lib/my_app/erb_helpers.rb
module MyApp
  module ERBHelpers
    class << self

      def render(partial_path, binding)
        dir_name, _, partial_name = partial_path.rpartition(File::SEPARATOR)
        file_name = "_#{partial_name}.html.erb"
        Erubis::Eruby.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'views', dir_name, file_name)).gsub("'", %q(\\\'))).result(binding)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Then I used it inside coffeescript file like this:

```
# in app/assets/javascripts/notifications.coffee
MyApp.notifications.templates =
  notice: '<%= ::MyApp::ERBHelpers.render 'application/notifications/notice', content: "%content%" %>'
  alert: '<%= ::MyApp::ERBHelpers.render 'application/notifications/alert', content: "%content%" %>'

MyApp.notifications.create_elem = (type, content) -> MyApp.notifications.templates[type].replace('%content%', content)
```

**PS:** I tested it on Rails 5.0 app

Answer (score -2):

In fact, it works for me.
You need to do:

```
= render 'way/to/partial'
```

where 'way/to/partial' is relative path under existing assets folder.
Wired thing is that in the path, you need to omit the first level folder under assets.

Comment: What ? How can it be that giving a different parameter to a method making it available ?? Do you have a working example somewhere ?