# How can I render a partial from .js.erb file in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails application I have dragdrop.js.erb in /assets/javascript folder. In which I have an ajax block which should render a partial in a div with an on click action. I tried many things but I can't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
 $.ajax({  
   type: "GET",    
   url: "<%=  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.cookbooks_path %>",
   success: function(resp){
  $("#property").load("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'recipes/package_form') %>") 
   }
```

Comment: post related code that you have tried, so that we can help you

Comment: Whats the error/exception? Anyways, any special reason to keep `.js.erb` into `assets/javascript` instead of `app/views`?

Comment: `undefined method `render' for #<Chefmaster::Application:0x00000002d73f50>
  (in /home/cookmaster/workspace/test/app/assets/javascripts/dragdrop.js.erb)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asset Pipeline**

Firstly, you need to make sure that you **don't** use any Rails dynamic path helpers in your javascript directly.

The issue is that if you pre-compile your asset pipeline, you'll typically find these dynamic path helpers won't work correctly. Although there's nothing "wrong" with it - I tend to keep Rails back-end code completely separate from the front-end, as to ensure the versatility of the application:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
   $.ajax({  
     type: "GET",    
     url: "/cookbooks"
  });
});
```

This will send a "naked" Ajax request (no params / body) to your controller backend:

```
#app/controllers/cookbooks_controller.rb
Class CookbooksController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @cookbooks = Cookbook.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js #-> loads /views/cookbooks/index.js.erb
      end
   end
end
```

The trick here is that you can now populate your `index.js.erb` file with the params necessary to render the partial:

```
#app/views/cookbooks/index.js.erb
$("#property").html("<%=j render :partial => 'recipes/package_form' %>")
```

--

This should work for you

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `render` in `assets`, however, [`render` is not available in `assets`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1370)

You should move your `.js.erb` file to an appropriate directory under `app/views`

---

Here are some other similar question:

1. [Rendering A Partial In Assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336072/rendering-a-partial-in-assets)
2. [Rails JS ERB File Cannot Find Method Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render)
3. [When rendering a partial from tasks.js.coffee.erb - undefined,
   render](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1370)