# Not displaying ajax response in haml

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I am trying to display response from the rails server in a `div`.

ajax call is like this

```
$.get('/news/search?search=' + existingString, function(data) {
  $("#results").html("");
  console.log(data);
  len=data.length;
  $('#result').append('#{escape_javascript(render("newsdisplay") )}');
```

**_newsdisplay.html.haml**

```
- if @results
  - @results.each do |anzen|
    %li.clearfix.postMain.allnews
     .wrapper
       %li
        .messaIcon
          .icon
            %img{:src => anzen.news_image.thumb.url}
        .messaCon
          .areaDay.clearfix
            %p.messaTextCon
            グループ名:
            %span= anzen.news_name
```

**search action**

```
def search
  if params[:search].present?
    @results = News.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'news/search', to: 'news#search', as: :newssearch
```

I am getting the response from the server correctly. But no change in the page.But in console the full page with rendered response is displayed. Can anyone guess the issue

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet is plain js, right? You cannot render the `newsdisplay` inline JS, the HTML has to be rendered before, so you should have a search.js.erb as a view that just renders the newsdisplay view.

The this example:

[How can I render a partial from .js.erb file in rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382535/how-can-i-render-a-partial-from-js-erb-file-in-rails-4)

Comment: No .Its search.html.haml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#result').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'newsdisplay') )");
```

Comment: You are making a ajax call so your response should be either js or json.so change your search.html.haml file to search.js.erb @Akhil Sudhakaran